# Which version will google index from webmaster tools?

Tags: https, google-search-console

I have just launched a site . I am using the https protocol. So my domain is https:// example

I created a google webmaster tools account and verified I was the owner of https:// example and https:// example

I then tried to set my preferred domain in the site settings (https:// example) and it asked to verify that I was the owner of http://example and http://www. example

So I now have 4 different verions of the site set up in webmaster tools. I set my preferred domain as example.com , it doesnt allowed me pick a prefered protocol.

My question is , how will google know to index the https:// and not the http:// ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Redirect

Assuming you want everything indexed under https://example.com, you can redirect all requests to http://example.com, http://www.example.com, and https://www.example.com to be sent to https://example.com.

This is the best method as it keeps everything clean and only directly accessible via the one domain and protocol. Google (and all other users) will follow the redirect if they try to access any of the other variations.

## rel canonical

Another alternative is to use rel=canonical and set this to the preferred domain. This allows you to still serve the same content over both protocols, the root domain, and www. subdomain, but sets the preferred domain as the one that should be indexed as the location for accessing that content.

## noindex

A third option would be to specify noindex on all content served from the non-preferred domains / protocol. This would ensure that Search Engines would only index the content served on the preferred domain (which doesn't have noindex set).

But I wouldn't recommend this as it's not good for SEO - if someone links to http://example.com and you have it noindexed, that link is disregarded by SEs. Whereas if you use redirect or rel canonical, the link is counted towards the page on your preferred domain that the canonical / redirect goes to.

---

To be clear, whenever using redirects or rel canonical, you must point it to the corresponding page on the preferred domain.
So http://example.com/some-page/ should redirect to https://example.com/some-page/, not just https://example.com/

You can't set any of this using Google Webmaster Tools, you'll need to set it on the server hosting your website. The way to do this depends on how your server is configured.

Comment: Thank you, all pages redirect to the corresponding https://  In webmaster tools I have added sitemap and robots.txt etc to the https:// property. Do I need to do that with the other versions in webmaster tools or will google know that they are just added so I can set a preferred domain ? Or is it even necessary to add the https:// version can i just add example.com and www.example.com (the http protocal is added by default). The only reason I added the http versions to wmt were because it kept asking me to verify that owned http:// and not just https://

Comment: Webmaster Tools is more for you to understand how Google sees your site than it is for you to tell Google how to index it (though you can do that a bit). It's best to set everything correctly on your server, that way all search engines will index it correctly, not just Google. So long as you've set up redirects from the http and www to the https root domain, then Google and all other SEs will follow the redirects and index only the https root domain.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response

Comment: Good answer. And I would add that you should register all four variants in Google Search Console like you have done, though in reality you will only see interesting information in one version if you have all redirects set up. But handy to have others registered in case Google spots a problem with one of them and wants to alert you to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to google:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

> Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element
>
> Suppose you want https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome/ to be the preferred URL, even though a variety of URLs can access this content. You can indicate this to search engines as follows:
>
> ```
> Mark up the canonical page and any other variants with a rel="canonical" link element.
> Add a <link> element with the attribute rel="canonical" to the <head> section of these pages: 
>
> <link rel="canonical" href="https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />
> ```

Comment: Thanks, Ive have the canonical url set to the https verions and set up a redirect in the htaccess file. I added a sitemap to the https:// property in the google. Do I have to do that for the rest of the propertys aswell? Or can  I just leave them lie dormant?

Comment: @Henrick sorry I don't know.